# MongoDB + Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, mlab

I am trying to integrate a project with Spring + MongoDB + Mongolab + JSF, I found many tutorials, but i didnt find how to configure a remote monogodb database (such as MongoLab) in the Spring Configuration XML file:

```
<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />
```

Where can I put the login credentials? Please help

Comment: Isn't this enough fo you: `<mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" username="" password=""/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working bloc of code

```
    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="domainName" port="portNumber" />

    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory"
              host="domainName"
              port="portNumber"
              username="userName"
              password="passWord"
              dbname="DBName"
              mongo-ref="mongo" />

     <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
         <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
     </bean>
```

I tried it and it is working 100% 
Thank you for your help